# What is the point of MyType(myVar) declaration in C++?

Tags: c++

In c++11 standard we can declare variable in an unusual way. We can declare `myVar` as `int(myVar);` instead of `int myVar`. What is the point of this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int(myVar);
    myVar = 1000;
    cout << myVar << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD** Actually there is a certain reason why I asked this. What looked innocent just stopped to compile when we tried to port some code from MSVC C++03 to GCC C++11.
Here is an example

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct MyAssert
    {
        MyAssert(bool)
        {
        }
    };

    #define ASSERT(cond) MyAssert(cond)

    void func(void* ptr)
    {
        ASSERT(ptr); // error: declaration of ‘MyAssert ptr’
                    // shadows a parameter #define ASSERT(cond) MyAssert(cond)
    }

    int main()
    {
        func(nullptr);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This has been possible in all versions of C and C++

Comment: @matt-mcnabb You right. Thank you. We were porting from MSVC C++03 to GCC C++11. May be that is why I decided that this is related to standard.

Comment: What did you intend for `ASSERT(ptr)` to mean?  Or to put it another way: what did it mean to MSVC C++03?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure.  I can even do this:

```
int (main)()
{
}
```

Parentheses serve to group things in C and C++.  They often do not carry additional meaning beyond grouping.  Function calls/declarations/definitions are a bit special, but if you need convincing that we should not be allowed to omit them there, just look at Ruby, where parentheses are optional in function calls.

There is not necessarily a point to it.  But sometimes being able to slap on some theoretically unnecessary parentheses helps make code easier to read.  Not in your particular example, and not in mine, of course.

Comment: This answer would be improved with an example of when it would make the code easier to read (not that I can think of one!)

Comment: I don't understand the mention of Ruby... Also: Function calls without parenthesis ==> Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int     main(void)
{
  int   *first_var[2];
  int   (*second_var)[2];

  std::cout << typeid(first_var).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(second_var).name() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Running this on my machine gives :

```
A2_Pi
PA2_i
```

The parenthesis in the declaration mostly serve the same purpose they do everywhere, group things that should be together regardless of the default priority order of the language.
Of course parenthesis with only one element inside is equivalent to just typing that element except in cases where parenthesis are mandatory (e.g function calls).

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not break backward compatibility if it can help it.

The C that it was developed from had this syntax.  So C++ inherited it.

A side effect of this backward compatibility are the vexing parse problems.  They have not proved sufficiently vexing to justify breaking backward compatibility.